# Gaussian Integral incorrect

Tags: probability-or-statistics, integral-equations

I'm trying to learn about the Gaussian Normal distribution using Mathematica.

So I defined my Gaussian like this

```
Gaus[x_, mu_, sigma_] = 1/(sigma*Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) E^(-(1/2) ((x - mu)/sigma)^2);
```

I just tried to integrate it

```
Integrate[Gaus[x, mu, sigma], x, Assumptions -> {sigma > 0}]
```

which gives me

```
-(1/2) Erf[(mu - x)/(Sqrt[2] sigma)]
```

I plot it using a manipulate block

```
Manipulate[Column[{
   Style["Gaussian Normal", Bold],
   Plot[Gaus[x, mu, sigma], {x, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   PlotRange -> Full],
   Style["Gaussian Integral", Bold],
   Plot[-(1/2) Erf[(mu - x)/(Sqrt[2] sigma)], {x, -5, 5}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> Full]
   }],
 {mu, -5, 5, 1}, {sigma, 0.5, 2, 0.5}]
```

This is what I get for mean=1 and stdev=1:

[image: Gaussian and Error function plot]

I don't understand why the erf function is going through (0/0) and is not shifted up by 1/2.

Comment: The correct integral is just `CDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The antiderivative `Integrate` isn't unique.

Try

```
Integrate[Gaus[x, mu, sigma], {x, -Infinity, x},Assumptions -> {sigma > 0}]
(*1/2 (1 + Erf[(-mu + x)/(Sqrt[2] sigma)])*)
```

to get the expected result!